# Generate data frame length (and column data) from function

Tags: r

I want to generate a data frame with a random length.

```
> head(df)
"id"    "age"
53      12        # randomly chosen data from fn1(){} and fn2(){}
146     31        #
343     22        #
...#randomly generated length from sample(50:5000,1)
```

The problem is that the way I'm trying is just repeat the same element over and over:

```
# This just repeats the same value instead of generating function over and over
a <- fn1(){}
rep(a,15)
[1] "S" "S" "S" "S" "S" "S" "S" ...
```

Ideally the column names I want to specify and assign a value from other functions:

```
# Generate length of data frame
df.length <- sample(50:500,1)

# Generate data for each row from function
df.column.id <- fn1(){}
df.column.age <- fn2(){}
...

df <- data.frame("id" = df.column.id, "age" = df.column.age, ...)
```

Unfortunately the rep function isn't working, so how can the data frame columns be generated from functions? I also tried `matrix(data = c(df.column.id, df.column.age), nrow = df.length)` didn't work as intended.

Edit:

replicate(10, RandomStatusColor(), simplify = "vector") is working to generate a vector of the function outputs.

Comment: cbind(col1 = replicate(10, RandomStatusColor(), simplify = "vector"), col2 = .... is what I was after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could help:

```
min_rownum <- 10
max_rownum <- 50
num_of_rows <- sample(seq(min_rownum, max_rownum), 1)
min_age <- 1 
max_age <- 50
age <- sample(seq(min_age, max_age), num_of_rows, replace = TRUE)
min_ID <- 50
max_ID <- 500
id <- sample(seq(min_ID, max_ID), num_of_rows)
df1 <- data.frame(id, age)
```

I tried to use variable names that would make the code self-explanatory.

The parameter `replace = TRUE` in the `sample()` function means that an element can be selected more than once. In the case of ages this is plausible, whereas IDs should be unique. The second argument of `sample()` defines how many elements should be chosen from the vector that is passed as a first argument.

---

The title of the question suggests that the data.frame should be generated by a function. In that case the above code can be wrapped into a function like this:

```
make_random_df <- function(min_rownum=10, max_rownum=50, min_age=1, max_age=50,
                       min_ID=50, max_ID=500) {
  num_of_rows <- sample(seq(min_rownum, max_rownum), 1)
  age <- sample(seq(min_age, max_age), num_of_rows, replace = TRUE)
  id <- sample(seq(min_ID, max_ID), num_of_rows)
  df1 <- data.frame(id, age)
}
```

Using this function, the data.frame can be created with

```
my_random_df <- make_random_df()
#> head(my_random_df)
#   id age
#1 461   7
#2  86  44
#3 319   8
#4 363  45
#5  59   3
#6 258  49
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that generates data samples of a given length (`len`) from a given vector (`vec`):

```
createData <- function(vec, len) {
  sample(vec, len, replace = TRUE)
}

nobs <- 20

df <- data.frame(id = createData(vec = c("a", "b", "c"), len = nobs),
                 age = createData(vec = seq(10, 50, 10), len = nobs))

df
```

Is this what you are after?

Comment: `createData` should scale as long as your `fn()`s return a vector like `c` and `seq` in the example. Can you show us one of your `fn()`s?